# Jquery onclick triggered automatically?

Tags: jquery, html

Im building a personal website and have some links at the top that I hope to make scroll to the appropriate section

I have this for one of the links :

```
        <li><a id="aboutClick" href= ""><i class="tiny material-icons ">speaker_notes</i> ABOUT</a></li>
```

and am hoping to redirect it to the about div

```
    <div id="about" class="container"> (insert about me section etc...)
```

anyway I was trying to make this happen by

```
var aboutLink = document.getElementById('aboutClick');
var aboutDiv = document.getElementById('about');
aboutLink.onClick = aboutDiv.scrollIntoView();
```

It works when i first open the page in a tab/browser, but if I refresh, or go to the page again after visiting other websites, it automatically scrolls to about

how can I stop this?

Comment: Try `aboutLink.onClick = aboutDiv.scrollIntoView;`

Answer (score -1):

Just for sanity, can you check there's no id appended to your URL?

If there isn't anything there, can you post a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?